# Shorten large number with javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have this large number:
**21212202382541035306949186015338569645685453497668055588619610488832**

Javascript automatically shortens it for me like this:
**2.1212202382540943e+67**

But since I put that inside a table cell with a fixed with, I need the number to be less or equal then 11 digits in total.

So in example, if I have the previous mentioned number, it should be converted to:
**~2.1212e+67**

And, if the number is:

**128330558031338336** it should show **~1.2833e+17**

So basically, if the length of a number is longer then 11 digits, it should start adding the powers of 10 to it and also start rounding the number.

How can I do this withing JavaScript?

I tried with `substring()`, but I have problems determining the exact powers to be shown.

---

*Edit*

The end script looks like this:

```
if ( num.length > 11 ) {
    num = parseFloat( num );
    var n = '~'+ num.toExponential( 4 );
} else {
    var n = num;
}
```

Thanks a lot [Black Maggie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003208/black-maggie)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential

There is a toExponential() in javascript

So if you want to have a total of 11 characters remaining in the exponential representation,
you may pass the number of digits remain after the decimal places

`toExponential(5)` may results `2.12122e+67` for your number `21212202382541035306949186015338569645685453497668055588619610488832`

Update: selected a better source from mozilla instead of w3school. Thanks @T.J. Crowder

Update 2: Source:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

For php, use `round()` seems possibly force a scientific notation conversion on the number.

Comment: +1 for `toExponential`. Better links: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.6 | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential

Comment: wow, thanks, I never knew there was such a function. And nice speed too. Welcome to SO.

Comment: +1, for the toExponential, would be nice though, if you would replace the link

Comment: Additional question, is there a similar function in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case [toPrecision](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp) would be more appropriate.

You may need some trickery to fit your table cell if your numbers deviate greatly. For example try with 8 significant digits, test string length, and if too long, try again with 7 and perhaps even 6 and 5.

Update: Ok, I played a bit with the following code:

```
num = new Number(<your num>);
alert("prec: " + num.toPrecision(5) + " exp: " + num.toExponential(4));
```

Sample output:

```
prec: 364.00 exp: 3.6400e+2
prec: 3.6435e+13 exp: 3.6435e+13
```

I would say it depends on if you want to always see exponential numbers or only when needed. In the former case, toPrecision() is better because it leaves the number fixed point if possible so you can get higher precision in the same string length. If you want always exponential numbers, then toExponential() is better. if your numbers will always be big enough to be exponential, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: [VisioN's Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427929/shorten-large-number-with-javascript#comment21819231_15427965)